# C# Entity Framework Core 3.1 explicit loading of multiple relationships causing a Cartesian Explosion, how to Split Query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, eager-loading, entity-framework-core-3.1

I had a scaling problem in a production environment. A small numbers of records processed fine. But larger volumes took exponentially longer. These classes are just to illustrate the point.

```cs
Party {
   DateTime When { get; set; }
   ICollection<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
}
    
Attendee {
   ICollection<Gift> Gifts { get; set; }
   ICollection<Allergy> Allergies { get; set; }
}
    
IEnumerable<Party> GetAllPartiesByDate(DateTime date) {
   var parties = Context.Parties             
                    .Include(p => p.Attendees).ThenInclude(a => a.Gifts)
                    .Include(p => p.Attendees).ThenInclude(a => a.Allergies)
                    .Where(p.When == date)
                    .ToList();
   return parties;
}
```

With 4 matching parties, and 7 attendees at each party, where each attendee has 3 gifts and 2 allergies
That's **172** rows in the DB across 4 tables
`4 + (4*7) + (4*7*3) + (4*7*2)`

EF returns that via a single SQL query with **168** rows, not too bad.
`4 * (7) * (3) * (2)`

But make each of those values just 10 times larger and you get **142,840** rows in the DB
`40 + (40*70) + (40*70*30) + (40*70*20)`
But the results set from the singe EF query explodes on each successive one to many relationship and *tries* to return `40 * 70 * 30 * 20` **1,680,000** rows

When using more modern versions of Entity Framework Core the solution to a Cartesian Explosion is to use **AsSplitQuery**

For unfortunate technical reasons we cannot update Entity Framework Core past version 3.1.

But how can you implement AsSplitQuery in EF Core 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to:

- **Explicitly load instances you need** in sperate queries making sure to **only** return the instances you need.
- **Keep entity tracking ON**. If off EFs entity resolution (AKA [fix-up navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)) on subsequent queries using the same context will return duplicate instances *instead* of the same instance already loaded into the context. Tracking is also needed for Lazy Loading.
- **Disable auto detection of changes** during load. This stops entities being marked with the edited state.
- **Explicitly tell EF that properties have been loaded**. This prevents lazy loading from reaching the DB despite having instances in memory already.

*Remember AutoDetectChangesEnabled is **not** the same mechanism as QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking aka AsNoTracking*

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The strategy for split loading when you know the second order volume is low.
/// I.e. We know there are lots of parties and attendees, but each attendee has a low number of gifts and allergies.
/// This loads parties and then everything else over two SQL queries
/// </summary>
IEnumerable<Party> GetAllPartiesByDate(DateTime date) 
{
    try
    {
        //Turn off change tracking, note this is NOT the same as AsNoTracking
        Context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        //Keep the search condition.
        IQueryable<Party> partyQuery = Context.Parties.Where(p.When == date);

        //For relationships where you know the count is small you can still use includes 
        //Thus producing a single SQL round trip. 
        //But projections do not honour includes so you must load from the DbSet via projected IDs instead. 
        var partyIDsQuery = partyQuery.Select(p => new { MatchPartyId = p.Id });

        //Join to projected IDs
        var attendeesQuery = Context.Attendees.Join(partyIDsQuery, a => a.PartyId, i => i.MatchPartyId, (a,i) => a)
           .Include(a => a.Allergies)
           .Include(a => a.Gifts);

        //Get it into memory
        var allAttendees = attendeesQuery.ToList();

        //C# group by not SQL group by
        var allAttendeesLookup = allAttendees.GroupBy(a => a.PartyId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => new List<Attendee>(g));

        //Triger an SQL call with ToList, this creates instances of Party.
        List<Party> parties = partyQuery.ToList();

        foreach(var party in parties)
        {
            //Assign the loaded list
            if(allAttendeesLookup.TryGetValue(party.Id, out var attendees))        
                party.Attendees = attendees;
            else
                party.Attendees = new List<Attendee>(0);

            //Tell EF you have loaded it
            Context.Entry<Party>(party).Collection(p => p.Attendees).IsLoaded = true;
        }

        return parties;                
    }
    finally
    {
        Context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The strategy for split loading when you know the volume is high for every relationship.
/// This loads parties and then each relationship via sperate SQL queries.
/// </summary>
IEnumerable<Party> GetAllPartiesByDate(DateTime date) 
{
    try
    {
        //Turn off change tracking, note this is NOT the same as AsNoTracking
        Context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        //Keep the search condition.
        IQueryable<Party> partyQuery = Context.Parties.Where(p.When == date);

        //Load just the attendees via projection as no includes are being used and it's a top level relationship
        var allAttendeesGroup = partyQuery.Select(p => new { p.Id, d.Attendees });
        var allAttendeesLookup = allAttendeesGroup.ToDictionary(e => e.Id, e => e);

        //Load party
        List<Party> parties = partyQuery.ToList();

        //Get link IDs for leaves
        var partyIDsQuery = partyQuery.Select(p => new { MatchPartyId = p.Id });
        var attendeeIDsQuery = Context.Attendees.Join(partyIDsQuery, a => a.PartyId, i => i.MatchPartyId, (a,i) => a)
            .Select(a => a. new { MatchAttendeeId = a.Id });

        //Load leaves and make lookups in mem
        var allGiftsQuery = Context.Gifts.Join(attendeeIDsQuery, g => g.AttendeeId, i => i.MatchAttendeeId, (g,i) => g);
        var allGifts = allGiftsQuery.ToList();
        var allGiftsLookUp = allGifts.GroupBy(g => g.AttendeeId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => new List<Gift>(g));

        var allAllergysQuery = Context.Allergys.Join(attendeeIDsQuery, a => a.AttendeeId, i => i.MatchAttendeeId, (a,i) => a);
        var allAllergys = allAllergysQuery.ToList();
        var allAllergysLookUp = allAllergys.GroupBy(a => a.AttendeeId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => new List<Gift>(g));

        //Connect everything
        foreach(var party in parties)
        {
            //Assign the loaded list
            if(allAttendeesLookup.TryGetValue(party.Id, out var attendees))        
                party.Attendees = attendees;
            else
                party.Attendees = new List<Attendee>(0);

            //Tell EF you have loaded it
            Context.Entry<Party>(party).Collection(p => p.Attendees).IsLoaded = true;

            //Connect leaves
            foreach(var attendee in party.Attendees)
            {  
                if(allGiftsLookUp.TryGetValue(attendee.Id, out var gifts))        
                    attendee.Gifts = gifts;
                else
                    attendee.Gifts = new List<Gift>(0);
                Context.Entry<Attendee>(attendee).Collection(a => a.Gifts).IsLoaded = true;

                if(allAllergysLookUp.TryGetValue(attendee.Id, out var allergys))        
                    attendee.Allergies = allergys;
                else
                    attendee.Allergies = new List<Allergy>(0);
                Context.Entry<Attendee>(attendee).Collection(a => a.Allergies).IsLoaded = true;
            }
        }
        return parties; 
    }
    finally
    {
        Context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

You will likely need to use a mixture of the two strategies depending on the expected volumes for each relationship you are dealing with.

Comment: This obviously has the same integrity drawbacks as AsSplitQuery and should only be used on large datasets with many dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try Load entites from the end:

```cs
IEnumerable<Party> GetAllPartiesByDate(DateTime date) 
{
    var gifts = contex.Gifts
        .Where(gift => gift.Attendee.Party.When == date)
        .ToList();

    var allergies = contex.Allergies
        .Where(a => a.Attendee.Party.When == date)
        .ToList();

    var attendees = context.Attendees
        .Where(a => a.Party.When == date)
        .ToList();

    // At this proint EF Core should fixup navigation properties when they are tracked
    var parties = Context.Parties              
        .Where(p => p.When == date)
        .ToList();

   return parties;
}
```

Also you can try extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), Disclaimer: I'm one of the creators.

just add `ToLinqToDB()` in your query:

```cs
IEnumerable<Party> GetAllPartiesByDate(DateTime date) 
{
   var parties = Context.Parties             
        .Include(p => p.Attendees).ThenInclude(a => a.Gifts)
        .Include(p => p.Attendees).ThenInclude(a => a.Allergies)
        .Where(p.When == date)
        .ToLinqToDB()
        .ToList();
   return parties;
}
```

Comment: Yeh my solution was reloading the parties each time (not good). The production "Where" condition is much more complicated than just a date check though which is why i need to only specify it once.

Comment: I can only suggest to code which I see. You can get just Id's of Parties and load children using these Id's using filter by `Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve a similar result by breaking down the query into multiple steps using `Select` and `ThenInclude`. This may not be as efficient as `AsSplitQuery`, but it can help you to mitigate the **Cartesian Explosion issue**.

```
IEnumerable<Party> GetAllPartiesByDate(DateTime date)
 {
   var parties = Context.Parties
                 .Where(p => p.When == date)
                 .Include(p => p.Attendees)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Gifts)
                 .Include(p => p.Attendees)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Allergies)
                 .ToList();

// Explicit loading for large volumes
foreach (var party in parties)
{
    Context.Entry(party)
           .Collection(p => p.Attendees)
           .Query()
           .Include(a => a.Gifts)
           .Include(a => a.Allergies)
           .Load();
}
```

This approach fetches the *parties* with basic information first and then explicitly loads the related entities for each party. This allows you to control the number of rows returned in each step, potentially reducing the risk of Cartesian Explosion.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach is too slow for high volumes of data as each time round the loop generates a separate SQL call.